# Getting a PPID of a process with wmi library

Tags: python, wmi

I want to extract the PPID of a process by his PID, don't know how and need help

So far I was able to print all running processes for the user to choose from,  and created a variable that receives a PID of a process from the list, now I need to find the PPID of that process and extract it with its name.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Win32_Process` class in the WMI library to retrieve the Parent Process ID (PPID). Below is a Python script that does that:

```
import wmi

# Create WMI client
c = wmi.WMI()

def get_ppid_and_name(pid):
    for process in c.Win32_Process(ProcessId=pid):
        ppid = process.ParentProcessId
        pname = process.Name
        return ppid, pname

# User defined process id
pid = int(input("Enter the PID: ")) # Or whatever pid you have
ppid, pname = get_ppid_and_name(pid)
print("Parent Process ID: ", ppid)
print("Parent Process Name: ", get_ppid_and_name(ppid)[1])
```

The function `get_ppid_and_name` accepts a process ID, and iterates over the processes returned by `Win32_Process(ProcessId=pid)`. This WMI query will return a list with a single process that matches the provided PID.

It then extracts the `ParentProcessId` and `Name` from the process object. We get the PPID and then call the same function again to get the name of the parent process.

Hope this helps :)